Finding $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{1/x}}{1+ e^{1/x}}$ by L'Hopital rule
When I apply the L'Hopital rule for finding this limit $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{1/x}}{1+ e^{1/x}}$$ I get $1$ as the answer.
But this limit actually does not exist if I divide numerator and denominator by $e^{1/x}$ to obtain
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{1+ e^{-1/x}}$$ as left hand limit which comes to be zero and right hand limit equal to $1$
So which answer is correct and Where am I doing wrong?

A better way to do is to find $\lim_{x\to 0^+}$ by doing a substitution of $u=1/x$ then this would be $\lim_{u\to +\infty}\frac{e^u}{1+e^u}$ which you can then do L'H on and similarly, do the same for $\lim_{x\to 0^-}$ which instead causes $u\to -\infty$ and see if these values agree.

You can apply L'Hôpital's rule in order to determine$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{e^{1/x}}{1+e^{1/x}};$$you will get $1$, which is the correct answer.
However, you cannot apply L'Hôpital's rule in order to determine$$\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{e^{1/x}}{1+e^{1/x}},$$since, in that case, you don't have an indetermination of the type $\frac00$ or of the type $\frac\infty\infty$ ($\lim_{x\to0^-}\left(1+e^{1/x}\right)=1$).

I have read also that L'Hôpital's theorem can also be used in the form anything/infty.

The original limit does not exist: as $x \to 0^-$ we have $1/x \to -\infty$ and hence $e^{1/x} \to 0$ and $\dfrac {e^{1/x}} {e^{1/x} + 1} \to 0$, while as $x \to 0^+$ we have $e^{1/x} \to \infty$ and $\dfrac {e^{1/x}} {e^{1/x} + 1} \to 1$. You correctly noticed this when you multiplied the numerator/denominator by $e^{-1/x}$, which is a valid step since $e^{-1/x} \ne 0$ for $x$ near $0$.
L'Hoptal's rule is not admissible on the two-sided limit since the limit $\lim_{x \to 0} e^{1/x}$ does not exist (for this purpose, let's say we count being "equal" to $\pm \infty$ as existing) for the above reason. L'Hopital's rule requires the limits of the numerator/denominator to exist and either both be $0$ or both be $\pm \infty$. As José Carlos Santos says, you can apply L'Hopital's to the right-side limit.

L'Hopital's theorem states that:
if both numerator and denominator are differentiable in an $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $0$, then, if the limit $\dfrac{N'(x)}{D'(x)}$ exists and equals $L$, then the limit $\dfrac{N(x)}{D(x)}$ exists and equals $L$.
In your case:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}N(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} e^\tfrac{1}{x}$$
does not exist because the one-sided limits are different.
Therefore $N(x), D(x)$ are not continuous at $0$ and, therefore, not differentiable at $0$ and any neighborhood of $0$.

i believe l'hopital's its full generality sallows non-differentiability at $0$, just needs differentiability in some punctured neighborhood $(-\epsilon, 0) \cup (0, \epsilon)$ of $0$. think strictly speaking you don't even need the functions to be defined at the limiting point
